# How can you use an OR statement for 2 partial texts (one OR the other) within a Match statement within an IF statement in VBA?

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

I want to make a function that will check the list A2:A100 for the cells that contain the text "DP" or "DX"  (e.g. DPCV, DXBB, VBDP) and put the text "Good" in B2:B100 . If not, then I want to insert in B2:B100 a value using Vlookup. Here is a rough example to get the idea.

```
=If ( IsNumber(Match("DP"or"DX" , A2)), "Good", VLOOKUP(D2,Table_Example,2,0))
```

I put IsNumber just to return True or False for the If statement. Maybe its not necessary.
Any ideas?

Comment: You say 'contains'. So is `DP` or `DX` part of a larger string?

Comment: Basically we have a list with text inside  A2:A100 and for each one im trying to apply the above statement. i will edit it in .

Comment: Not what I meant. Do you have a small set of sample data instead? Because if you literally meant to search for `DP` or `DX` you could just use `OR`

Comment: Its a list full of data like : DDLR,DP,DPPR,DX,DXLR and I just need to find the ones that contain "DP"or "DX".  this will define the value of B cell of the same row based on the function i tried to make above... Is it just '''OR'''  inside '''Match''' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this construct then:

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(A2,{"*DP*","*DX*"})),"Good",VLOOKUP(D2,Table_Example,2,0))
```

Not sure if you'd need to enter it through CSE.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i was looking for, I tried it and it worked ! Thank you.